# python multi agent simulation packages

Tags: python, agent

Are there any multi-agent-simulation packages in Python which can be used to simulate market behaviour? I tried to install SimPy but it does not seem suitable.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.activestate.com/blog/2010/06/must-have-python-packages-finance

Comment: @Stephen Younger, Was this helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone googles this question, I recently came accross this package: https://github.com/javipalanca/spade. It has a nice book-like tutorial, that explains not only the usage but the concept behind it.

I don't see many other options in Python, I would appreciate if anyone can show some others.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Mesa**, a multi-agent-simulation package in Python:

- https://mesa.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html
- https://github.com/projectmesa/mesa